# When resizing, make the window transparent with a dotted-line border

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm asking this question ahead of time, since I haven't gotten around to attempting an actual, real implementation yet. Win32 (C++) is turning out to be a colossal pain to program. But, my question is this:

I want to make my application's window become fully transparent with a dotted perimeter when resizing the window. How would I accomplish this? Think of what happens in Windows 3/3.1 (I believe it was this version) when resizing a window. Everything goes transparent, with a dotted-outline where the mouse is moving, then it repaints the entire contents. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

A while ago, I tried handling the `WM_(ENTER/EXIT)SIZEMOVE` messages and make use of `SetWindowLong()` to set the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended style, but my window became (indefinitely) pass-through, and when the window's focus was killed, it could never again regain focus.

Do I need to handle other messages like `WM_NCLBUTTON(DOWN/UP)`? I have a boolean flag to tell me when to halt drawing during resizing, and the logic for determining when I'm resizing works perfectly, but I cannot get the visuals to work. I'm not sure which parts of the Win32 API to actually use. I've done some research, and `uxtheme.lib`/`.h` seems promising, but I'm not sure how that would work with `WM_NCPAINT`, which I have been using with (some) luck.

**EDIT**

I need to clarify something, in case anyone was confused or unsure of what I meant. What I meant by the Windows 3.1/3 resizing scenario is that *once* `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` has occurred, the window (controls, caption, frame) should be made entirely invisible, and the window's nonclient-region's perimeter should display a dotted-outline of sorts. Then, only *until* the resize has been finished, when `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` has occurred should the entire window (controls, caption, frame) be fully redrawn, updated, and returned to its normal, functional state. Sorry for any miscommunication!

Comment: `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` doesn't actually make anything transparent - all it does is change the order that windows are drawn.

Comment: "*I want to make my application's window become fully transparent with a dotted perimeter when resizing the window*" - why do you want this?  No sane Windows app does this, especially when "Show window contents while dragging" is enabled in Windows' settings.   Turn off that setting, and Windows itself will create the effect you are asking for automatically (globally for all windows, though).

Comment: @RemyLebeau My application uses a custom caption and frame I've developed using the ```WM_(NC) PAINT, CALCSIZE, ACTIVATE, etc``` messages, and I have not been able to get smooth resizing like the native frame. I thought it would be a nice way to make it look more professional and polished, because it's really jittery and unable to keep up with the mouse like the native frame.

Comment: If I could figure out how to get smooth operation, then I don't think I would need to do this (or anything else for that matter), but the jittery borders are bothering me so much that I feel like my dotted-outline would look rather nice and slick.

Comment: Not a solution, but an explanation of the symptoms: [The compositor is evil](https://raphlinus.github.io/ui/graphics/2020/09/13/compositor-is-evil.html).

Comment: @HeatSync "*I have not been able to get smooth resizing like the native frame*" - then you should have asked about THAT issue instead. What you have posted here is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title of your question, accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer... After so long, finally found it. Here's where I found it! http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/docking-toolbars-part-2# - Hope it helps anyone else possibly in my shoes!

And it turns out that the solution was rather simple. In fact, the core concept of what is explained is near-completely what I was thinking, yet I just had no idea how to implement it. The solution involves overriding the default `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONUP` (specifically when initiating a window movement) messages, and drawing a patterned rectangle which follows the position of the cursor. Then, afterwards, calling `SetWindowPos` or some other similar function to relocate the window.

Basically, block Windows from attempting to display anything graphics related until the resizing has been finished. Then, and only then, make Windows move the entire window in one huge, foul swoop.

Answer (score -2):

Based on Remy's comment, there is a global option and corresponding registry setting for this, so perhaps try setting the registry setting when the move starts and restoring it when the move finishes.

Unfortunately this doesn't work as Windows appears only to pick up the setting on restart, broadcasting WM_SETTINGCHANGE also doesn't trigger it, which is a pity as doing something yourself that the OS already has an implementation of do is rather a poor state of affairs.

Comment: Seems the flag is only read after restart.

Comment: Did the author of this proposed answer implement a quick proof-of-concept to observe the fitness of their global solution to a local problem? Did the PoC work as intended? Were there any observable glitches? That's your job, not ours. Our job is to vote on contributions.

Comment: @IInspectable With all due respect, it isn't my job to implement the OP's code either, when the OP already has code they can put a simple test into. As I said above, it seems the flag is only read after a restart, but I haven't put that in the answer as there may be another event to trigger a reload of the setting I haven't found.

Comment: When you post an answer, you need to **know** that it solves the issue. A PoC is a common way to verify this. Creating a standard Windows application in Visual Studio takes literally less than a minute. Add 3 more minutes to implement your suggested approach, another minute to test. If you cannot invest 5 minutes of your time to verify fitness of your solution, then you should post a comment and have someone else pick it up from there. Asking moderators that already invested **their** reputation to additionally invest their time to do your work is a rather odd inquiry.

Comment: @IInspectable I've been here 12 years mate, I don't need you to tell me what to do. A tentative answer is an answer, and therefore is not a comment.

Comment: I've been here 8 years. You can safely assume that I know how to figure out how long you've been here, should I care to know. Thing is, I don't, as that information isn't relevant to what I wrote previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231208/discussion-between-pete-kirkham-and-iinspectable).